# os.stat failing on file with funky characters

Tags: python, windows-xp

Using Python 2.6.5 on Windows XP, I'm processing a directory of files by calling os.stat on them to obtain their size. The script is failing when it reaches a particular file that happens to have non-ASCII characters embedded within the name. The exception being thrown is that os.stat couldn't find the file specified. I know the file is there because I can play in iTunes or VLC Media Player.

The name of the file in question is

```
1-02 Só Danço Samba (Jazz Samba).m4a
```

Just in case the characters aren't being displayed, the string is

```
'1-02 So\xb4 Danc\xb8o Samba (Jazz Samba).m4a'
```

Is there something I should or could be doing to make the name acceptable to os.stat? BTW, trying to open the file in python also fails for the same reason.

Comment: Where does your script get the file name from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inserting the line `# coding=UTF-8` at the top of your python file (only makes a difference for unicode in your script, as Philipp points out), and make sure you are storing the file names as unicode instead of str.

Tested with the following:

```
# coding=UTF-8

import os
fname = u'/temp/1-02 Só Danço Samba (Jazz Samba).m4a'
print(os.stat(fname))
```

Comment: The first one would help only for file names that are hard-coded in the source file. The second point is more important: Unicode strings should be used for all file and directory names (e.g. as the argument of the `listdir` function).

Comment: You're right, I forgot the point of what I was doing as I tested it.

Comment: The name comes from doing an os.walk through the directory tree. How do I convert the string to unicode (or is it from unicode)? How do I write the loop to use unicode strings instead of regular strings?

Comment: If you provide a unicode `top` path argument to os.walk, it should provide unicode results.  It sounds like you're feeding it a str.